# Qt - работа с файлами проекта

Tags: проект, qt

Имеется проект на Qt - сделанный в виде приложения(app). Требуется его переработать в библиотеку, длч использования классов и файлов в основном приложении

Answer (score 2):

1.В файле проекта заменить :

```
TEMPLATES = app
```

на

```
TEMPLATES = lib
```

2.Посмотреть

- [Как экспортировать функции и классы из DLL и аналоги](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/faq/?id=3572)
- документация по qMake "Building a Library"